# lambda expression to assign a member function pointer

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, member

I need the syntax for a lambda expression that will return a pointer to a member function.

For example I have class A:

```
class A
{
int x;
void (A::*SomeFunction)();
}
```

I want to set SomeFunction to a lambda. I tried doing it like this:

```
A a();
a.SomeFunction = [this](){ printf("Hello from lambada %d",this->x);};
```

The problem is that:

```
[this](){ printf("Hello from lambda %d",this->x);};
```

does not give me a pointer to a member function of class A. it gives me a pointer to a normal function. How do i declare inside the lambda that this is a member function of A.

Alternativly if such a thing isn't possible in cpp. How do you suggest I'll access variable x of class A from the function that SomeFunction is pointing at without using virtual functions (this kind of code will run about 700 times per second).

**Edit:**

To make it clear I do care about performance. but the main reason why I need this is specific design problems not performance.
I understand this is probably not possible to do in cpp.
Workarounds suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: What kind of machine are you running on where the cost of an extra virtual dispatch is anywhere close to 1/700 of a second?

Comment: you are calling `printf` and are worried about virtual methods ?!?

Comment: Why do you need that at all? Can you clarify about your use case please? Looks like a XY-problem for me.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Your motivation to stay away from virtual methods isnt very sound

Comment: _"this kind of code will run about 700 times per second"_ You may consider to add additional dispatching at compile time (without using a vtable) using the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern. Though that has some drawbacks as well.

Comment: Just use a `std::function` and move on. 700 calls per second is *nothing* and the (tiny) overhead of `std::function` will not be noticeable in a optimized build - says my crystal ball.

Comment: @Brian This is part of an ECS implemention. and I am simply not willing to create a new class for etch system i want to give the user the option to declare the system in the scene constructor or inheriate from the system class. systems can be nameless pieces of logic held inside a vector too. This is a design thing. if it's possible I want it. if not i'll use virtual functions or pass variable x as function arg (in this case x is a pointer to basically all the data in the application).

Comment: @tomerzeitune Pointer to function and pointer to member functions are not free either and have a similar cost to virtual function. If you want function you can reassign at runtime, there will be a cost. either from virtualisation or function pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> This is part of an ECS implemention. and I am simply not willing to create a new class for etch system i want to give the user the option to declare the system in the scene constructor or inheriate from the system class.

You want different behavior from the same class without any indirection? You'll have to give up one.

But you don't have to write a class for each system either. You can make the class a template, so the compiler can *generate* a class for each systems:

```
template<typename T>
struct A : private T {
    A(T function) noexcept : T{std::move(function)} {}

    void SomeFunction() {
        (*this)(this);
    }

    int x = 0;
};
```

It can then be used like that:

```
auto lambda = [](auto a){ printf("Hello from lambda %d",a->x); };
auto my_a = A{lambda}; // Generate a new A type from lambda

my_a.SomeFunction(); // calls the lambda!
```

Comment: I would rather use composition than inheritance in this scenario. The overall syntax would be cleaner in my view (for example, this manual call of `operator ()` is ugly)

Comment: @SergeyA private inheritance is effectively composition and benefits from EBO

Comment: Nice one ! How should i extend this concept for about 10 functions some can be implemented some not , I planned on using nullptr to mark an unimplemented function. If not possible I don't care calling functions that do nothing but is there anyway to declare them automatically incase they aren't declared in the template arguments ? It's the event system some events  are handled and some aren't. All returning void but taking all kind of arguments.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot EBO benefit comes at a price of ugly syntax. Not sure if it makes sense for OP to sacrifice one for another here.

Comment: @SergeyA It's not so ugly, in fact much less uglier and pointer to member function wich OP wanted to use, and it's only in the implementation, so the API stay clean.

Comment: @tomerzeitune you can have each lambda as a member, or inherit from each of them

Comment: @tomerzeitune be mindful that 10 function is a lot to implement at that point. using a class instead of 10 lambda is better.

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible for several reasons.

First, a pointer to member function is different in type from a pointer to stand-alone function, and non-capturing lambdas can only be converted to pointers to standalone functions.

Second, your lambda is capturing, and as such, it can not be converted to a pointer to function at all, and can only remain a functor of unspecified type.

However, you shouldn't think too much into it and just store a lambda in a `std::function`. Granted, you will end with virtual dispatch and some performance degradation associated with that, but 700 times a second is nothing, and you will never detect a hit because of virtual dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to add extra methods to a class after its definition. Therefore, since there are no methods in your class `A`, it's impossible to ever set `A::SomeFunction` to point to any non-static method of `A`. As a workaround, you could have

```
void (*SomeFunction)(A*);
```

and

```
A a {};  // note {} instead of ()
a.SomeFunction = [](A* a){ /* do something with a->x */ };
```

Comment: You could make this nicer by having the function pointer be called `SomeFunction_impl`, and have an inline api `void SomeFunction() {SomeFunction_impl(this); }` to hide it at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

Well following up for future people here's a workaround to make it look a bit nicer.

I created a template class

```
template <class Parent,class Return, class...Params>
struct MemberLambda
{
Parent* self; // pointer to self
void (*lambda)(Parent * self,Params...);//the lambda
MemberLambda() = default;//Constructor
MemberLambda(Parent* self, void(*lambda)(Parent* self,Params...)) : 
self(self),lambda(lambda) {};//Constructor

Return operator()(Params... p) const { return lambda(self,p...); };
void operator=(void (*lambda)(Parent* self, Params...)) {
    this->lambda = lambda;
    }
};
```

Usage in class:

```
class A {
public:
int someMember; 
MemberLambda<A, void, int, int> func = 
MemberLambda<A, void, int, int>(this, nullptr);
};
```

*Note in the example I set the lambda to `nullptr` but it can be set to a lambda expression.

In the example, the lambda is a member of `A` takes two `int`s and returns `void`.

User usage:

```
A a;
a.someMember = 3;
a.func = [](A* self, int a, int b){ std::cout << self->someMember + a + b; };
a.func(5,6);
```

Will output 14, which is 3 + 5 + 6.